# Limit of a sequence in the space $\ell_2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

I have difficulties in the following problem.

Let $H=\ell_2$ be the space of square-summable sequences. Let $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and $\{u^k\}\subset H$ be such that
$$
u^{k+1}=(1-\alpha)u^k+\alpha T(u^k),
$$
where
$$
T(u)=(0, u_1, u_2, u_3, \ldots,u_n, \ldots)
$$
for all $u=(u_1, u_2, u_3, \ldots,u_n, \ldots)\in H$. Choose $u^0\in H$ and $\alpha\in (0, 1)$ such that $\{u^k\}$ converges weakly to $0$ but does not converge strongly to $0$.

Thank you for all hints and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

$$u^k=\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki (1-\alpha)^i\alpha^{k-i} T^i(u^0).$$

Then for each $a\in\ell_2$ we have

$$(u^k,a)=\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki (1-\alpha)^i\alpha^{k-i} (T^i(u^0),a)=
\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki (1-\alpha)^i\alpha^{k-i} (u^0, T^{*i}(a)),$$

where $T^*(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)= (a_2,a_3,a_4\dots)$.

Now let $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and $a\in\ell_2$. We are going to show the weak convergence of the sequence $\{u^k\}$ to $0$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Since $\lim_{i\to\infty} ||T^{*i}(a)||^2=\lim_{i\to\infty} \sum_{n=i}^\infty a_n^2=0$ there exists a number $N$ such that $||T^{*i}(a)||<\varepsilon$ for each $i>N$. Since $\alpha\in (0,1)$ there should be a number $K\ge N$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^N \binom ki (1-\alpha)^i\alpha^{k-i}<\varepsilon$ for each $k>K$. Then for each $k>K$  we have

$$(u^k,a)=\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki (1-\alpha)^i\alpha^{k-i} (u^0, T^{*i}(a))=
\sum_{i=0}^N \binom ki (1-\alpha)^i\alpha^{k-i} (u^0, T^{*i}(a))+
\sum_{i=N+1}^K \binom ki (1-\alpha)^i\alpha^{k-i} (u^0, T^{*i}(a))\le
\varepsilon\max_i ||u^0||||T^{*i}(a)||+ \sum_{i=N+1}^K \binom ki (1-\alpha)^i\alpha^{k-i}\varepsilon\le \varepsilon||u^0||||a||+\varepsilon.$$

--

I suspect that for $u^0=(1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots)$ the sequence $\{u^k\}$ does not converge strongly to $0$, but now I see no simple way to do respective estimations.

Comment: Thank you for your construction. I would like to know how to show that $\{u^k\}$ is not strongly convergent to $0$ for such $u^0=(1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \ldots)$

Comment: I would like to know it too. :-) I took  the sequence $\{1/n\}$ of coordinates of $u^0$ only as an representative. I suspect that the sequence $\{u ^k\}$ is not strongly convergent to $0$ provided the coordinates of $u^0$ descend relatively slow. Unfortunately, I did not  devise such a sequence of coordinates having the additional property that the coordinates of elements of the sequence $\{u ^k\}$ are obtained by simple calculations.

Comment: But I can write a computer program and obtain for a given $u^0$, at least, an empirical evidence of the strong (not) convergence of the sequence $\{u^n\}$.

Comment: I wrote the program. I cannot surely talk about the strong (not) convergence. Moreover, I need to choose $\alpha$. I put $\alpha=1/2$. And it is not a surprise that the sequence $\{u^k\}$ generated by the formula $u^0_n=n^{-0.55}$ seems to diverge from $0$ much better than the sequence $\{u^k\}$ generated by the formula $u^0_n=n^{-1}$.